How to make custom hibernate FunctionContributor work in Spring Boot integration tests
I have implemented a custom FunctionContributor (anyinarray) in a Spring Boot project.
I managed to registered it as well, so it works in the application.
However, when created an integration test it failed with the following error:

ERROR: function anyinarray(text[], text[]) does not exist
No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add
explicit type casts.

It shows that the FunctionContributor is not registered.
Integration test class is annotated with @DataJpaTest.
I tried @SpringBootTest annotation as well.
I tried adding registration via test context definition of META-INF/service/org.hibernate.boot.model.FunctionContributor to replicate the normal application setup.
Is it possible to register FunctionContributors programatically or from via application properties?

Could you give us your FunctionContributor.contributeFunctions method implementation ?
I had the same pb when i migrate from spring boot 3.1 to 3.2.
My custom functions implementation, i wanted to register were incorrects.
before :
public class JsonBPathMatchCustomFunction extends StandardSQLFunction {
@Override
public void render(SqlAppender sqlAppender, List<? extends SqlAstNode> sqlAstArguments, SqlAstTranslator<?> translator) {}}

After :
public class JsonBPathMatchCustomFunction extends StandardSQLFunction {
@Override
public void render(SqlAppender sqlAppender, List<? extends SqlAstNode> sqlAstArguments, ReturnableType<?> returnType, SqlAstTranslator<?> translator) {}}

The "before" override render method is deprecated forRemoval=true, in hibernate-core 6.4.10 version.
If you are in the same situation, i have to choose the "after" override render method.
In my situation, it solved my pb.
